# My C code that is supposed to take positive values and end when -1 is inputted, and print the largest number is not working

Tags: c

Hi I am wondering why my code is not working. Here are the instructions for it: Suppose we want to determine the largest number of a series of non-negative real values entered by the user. The user repeatedly enters the values, one at a time, and finally enters the value −1 to indicate that there are no more values to enter. We then print the largest value entered by the user, on the screen. If the first number entered by the user is `−1` (i.e., the user enters no non-negative values), then we’ll print the message “Error: no data!” on the screen. (Your program doesn’t have to verify that the numbers are non-negative.).

Now here is my code. For reference, some combinations of numbers work such as `5 5 5 5 -1`, and `1 2 3 4 5 10 -1`. Other combinations don't work such as `1 -1`, `1 2 2 3 4 5 10 -1`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SENTINEL -1

int main(void) {
    
    double value = 0;
    double value2 = 0;
    double large = 0;
    
    printf("enter your values: ");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &value, &large);

    if (value == SENTINEL) {
        printf ("Error: no data!");
    } else {
        while (value != -1) {
            printf("enter value: ");
            scanf("%lf", &value2);
    
            if (value2 > value) {
                large = value2;
            }
    
            value = value2;
        }
    
        printf("%f\n", large ); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: rewrite your program with only one `scanf()` with only one variable, inside a loop, of course.

Comment: You should test `value2` just read against `large`, not against the first `value` read. Also, `value` is never updated, how can you end the `while loop` ?

Answer (score 1):

I did not see C language for a long time, but I think that something like this might work:

```
double value = SENTINEL;
double large = SENTINEL;

printf("enter your values: ");
while (scanf("%lf", &value) != -1) {
    if (value > large)
        large = value;
        
    if (value == SENTINEL)
        break;
}

if (large == SENTINEL)
    printf("Error no data\n");
else
    printf("%lf \n", large);

return 0;
```

Comment: To avoid an infinite loop on invalid input, the test should be: `while (scanf("%lf", &value) == 1)`

Answer (score 1):

The program does not work as coded because you compare the `value` to `value2` and update `value2`, you should instead compare to `large` and update the same variable.

Furthermore, you read 2 values in the first step and assume the second is larger than the first, ad the second is never tested against `SENTINEL`.

You should simplify the code:

- read one value at a time
- initialize `large` to a value that will change if the first value read is not `SENTINEL`
- update `large` if the value read is larger.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SENTINEL (-1)

int main(void) {
    double largest = SENTINEL;
    double value;
    
    printf("enter your values: ");
    while (scanf("%lf", &value) == 1) {
        if (value == SENTINEL)
            break;
        if (largest < value) {
            largest = value;
        }
    }
    if (largest == SENTINEL) {
        printf("Error: no data!\n");
    } else {
        printf("%f\n", largest);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also note that comparing floating point values for equality is not recommended as the comparison can fail due to infinitesimal differences coming from limited precision on intermediary results. In this case it is not an issue, but since the input are supposed to be non negative, testing for a negative input seems safer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double largest = -1.0;
    double value;
    
    printf("enter your values: ");
    while (scanf("%lf", &value) == 1) {
        if (value < 0.0)
            break;
        if (largest < value) {
            largest = value;
        }
    }
    if (largest < 0.0) {
        printf("Error: no data!\n");
    } else {
        printf("%f\n", largest);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would also recommend against comparing float/double values for equality/non-equality.  It will work fine for -1 as in this case, but exact comparison of many floating point values will fail due to the limited precision of float/IEEE-754.

Comment: @mmixLinus: good advice. answer amended with a simpler and safer approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SENTINEL -1

int main(void)
{
    double value = 0;
    double maxval = -1.0;
    int count = 0;
    int stat;

    while (value != SENTINEL) {
        printf("Enter a values (-1 when done)");
        do {
            printf(": ");
            stat = scanf(" %lf ",&value);
        } while (stat != 1);
        if (value != SENTINEL) {
            if (value > maxval)
                maxval = value;
            count++;
        }
    }

    if (count == 0)
        printf ("Error: no data!");
    else
        printf("%f\n",maxval); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `do`/`while` loop will run endlessly on invalid input such as if the user types `A`

Answer (score -1):

To help you, try to print values you read.
It seems you use `double` and you compare it to an `int` (-1).
If numbers given are only integers use the according variable type.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).